# How do I configure beans for a static wsdl, which is importing a root xsd of a hierarchical structure?

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl, spring-ws

I am implementing soap web services in a Spring environment. The xsd and wsdl definitions come from an external company, and I've implemented the endpoints already.
However, when exposing trying the wsdl-files to outside consumers through a `WsConfigurerAdapter`, I can't get it to work properly.
Here is what I have (for each of six services):

1. A static wsdl, referring to:
2. A xsd-filed called [service]Interface.xsd, which includes:
3. [service]_I.xsd, and [service]_O.xsd, referring to each operations input and output.
   The input and output files again refer to multiple other xsd files, which makes up the structure.
   As far as I understand, there are two main strategies for defining beans for wsdl's in a `WsConfigurerAdapter`. Either through `SimpleWsdl11Definition`, which can read a static wsdl-file. Or through `DefaultWsdl11Definition`, which can generate a wsdl based on an xsd schema. However, none of my resources fit into any tutorial i can find.

**The problem is inline xsd schemas**

I've been able to get the system to read hierarchical xsd-files, through `DefaultWsdl11Definition`, By using a SchemaCollection instead of a SimpleSchema. But unfortunately, my xsd-files generate no operations. Without operations, no service can be loaded into for example soap UI. The xsd-files themselves seems to be insufficiently defined for this approach.

The operations are defined in the static wsdl, however, but in the `SimpleWsdl11Definition`, there are no option to add a SchemaCollection.

And now I am wondering if the resources (wsdl/xsd) are simply in a bad format, or if I am missing something in the configuration of them.

Related:
[Publishing Static WSDL and related XSD schemas using Spring WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531159/publishing-static-wsdl-and-related-xsd-schemas-using-spring-ws)
Difference for me is that my xsd structure is a large tree of files.

[Spring Map a file to a Url / URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378829/spring-map-a-file-to-a-url-uri)
Here the imported xsd files are imported as a collection, but not in a static wsdl context, the wsdl is generated from the initial xsd.

Is it possible to combine the parts i need from each of these two, so that I make a bean of a static wsdl, but still can import the xsd files as a collection?
Are there any other ways to do it? For instance making a bean for each of the xsd files? (there are about 50 of them, so it is viable)

I have not included the documentation package by choice, as I hope this is answerable without it. Let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to combine the parts you need from each of these two, so that you make a bean of a static wsdl, but still can import the xsd files as a collection?

Yes, you can use the wsdl:types element to import an external XSD schema into a WSDL document.

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/types" schemaLocation="types.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

You can also use the wsdl:import element to import an external WSDL document into a WSDL document.

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://www.example.com/service" location="service.wsdl"/>
```

For more information, see:

https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_types
https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_import

I hope all this information is relevant

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this does not really answer the question about configuring the files for exposure. Relative references does not work, which is the premise of my question.

Comment: how to expose that wsdl that imports another wsdl in Spring ?